# One flutter screen should be working the entire time regardless of whether i am on that screen or another

Tags: multithreading, flutter, dart

I am making a an app with 3 main screens: a reminders list, a homescreen, and a chatbot. The chatbot I will integrate in using Dialogflow, and i've completed the todo list. What the homescreen does is display pulse and temp taken from arduino through a bluetooth connection and if either exceeds or falls below a certain threshold then a call should be initiated. I currently did the call initiation and the pulse and temp values are hardcoded in for now. But if I go to another screen, the homescreen obviously doesn't do its job. What is the way I can make the homescreen kind of like the main thread . Basically even if i am on the chatbot screen, the homescreen should be checking if temp and pulse are abnormal and initiating calls if required.
I am not sure what concept this falls under so any help is appreciated.
[image: homescreen]

[image: reminders]
[image: chatbot]

Comment: Try creating a service for this which can run even in background if you link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Isolate class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html) to achieve this.

An isolate has its own memory and a single thread of execution that runs an event loop even in background until you kill Isolate.

Here is the [example](https://gist.github.com/jebright/a7086adc305615aa3a655c6d8bd90264) of how to use Isolate in flutter

There is also flutter package available for Isolate [flutter_isolate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate)

Comment: Also, what if i wanted this to function while the app wasn on, like i was on instagram but still wanted my pulse and temp to be updated?

Comment: I think Isolate will work when app is in background mode but I am not 100% sure. And Isolate gonna be killed when you kill application from background.